# If statement in CustomListArray

Tags: android, if-statement, adapter

What is wrong with the if cause? I want to change the displayed Icon dependent to the first position in my `singleListItemArray`. Without the if, the picture get displayed. I also checked the content of singleListItemArray[0]/product. It is correct.

```js
class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] dataListFinal) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_datalist ,dataListFinal);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater iteminflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = iteminflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_datalist, parent, false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon_product);

        String singleListItem = getItem(position);
        Log.d("singleListItem",singleListItem);
        String[] singleListItemArray = singleListItem.split("\t");
        String product = singleListItemArray[0];
        String label = singleListItemArray[1];

        [...]

        if (product == "Pc"){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pc);
        }

        Log.d("productausarray", product);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

do

```
if (product.equals("Pc"))
```

used `.equals()` for `string` comparison

Comment: Thank you. I just mentioned that there is also another whitespace before my `Pc` need to check from where it comes. Thank you